# dropDestinationDatabase option on Web Deployment Commandline Tool

Tags: database, msdeploy, automated-deployment

Ho,

I'm trying to get msdeploy commandline tool to copy databases from dev to test.

It seems to work except that I want to drop the databases on test and then recreate them

```
-verb:sync -source:dbFullSql="Data Source=DEVSERVER;Initial Catalog=XXX_Application;Integrated Security=true",dropDestinationDatabase=true -dest:dbFullSql="Data Source=111.111.111.111;Initial Catalog=XXX_Application;uid=admin;pwd=xxx;Integrated Security=false",dropDestinationDatabase=true
```

This is my command line.

Why is it ignoring the dropDestinationDatabase option?

The admin user has permissions for drop.

Regards,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to append the parameter to only the -dest:dbFullSql switch

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569036(WS.10).aspx