# Migrating a SQL Server test database from development to test environment with a script?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-migration

I'm doing a lot of development with a weekly demo to client. I have a development environment and a test environment.

Every week I have to backup the database on development and then use remote desktop to restore it on the test server.

I've tried using MSdeploy to move the database but haven't been able to get the dropDestinationDatabase switch working. See [dropDestinationDatabase option on Web Deployment Commandline Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854670/dropdestinationdatabase-option-on-web-deployment-commandline-tool)

Does anyone know a good, simple technique to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Gate's [Sql Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/) allows you to automate promotes and connect your database to SVN.

I've not done it myself but I reckon that if the database is in svn then you could hook in a [Team City build trigger](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Build+Trigger) to not only automate sql changes but monitor them in the same place as code changes.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Once in source control, it's possible to set up automation using appropriate command line tools as described in this paper: http://downloads.red-gate.com/HelpPDF/ContinuousIntegrationForDatabasesUsingRedGateSQLTools.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[RedGate Tools](http://www.red-gate.com/) (SQL Compare, SQL Data Compare)

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 onwards, the [GDR R2 database project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed&displaylang=en) is also a good solution.

Comment: I'd prefer a script that I can just execute, can I create one with these tools?

Comment: @Rob Stevenson-Leggett: The redgate tools can create a TSQL synch script; GDR uses a cmd line tool and manifest.

Comment: @Rob Stevenson-Leggett, may I ask why do you want script for this?

Comment: Because I want a repeatable process that doesn't take half an hour.

Comment: If you're looking to just copy a database, Red Gate SQL Packager might work for you as it does both schema and data. However, it lacks the sophistication of SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare.